# I got a refusal for a UK Visit Visa and want to re-apply

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I am working with one of the Five Star properties in Saudi Arabia and I'm an Indian Citizen.
I applied for a UK visit visa but it got refused because of the attached statement[image]

I deposited my own savings in my account and I didn't think that it may have raised doubt. How I should explain the deposit I made into my account?
It's almost one month since I made the deposit - can I take a fresh bank statement and apply again?

Can anyone advise?

Comment: As the letter mentions the paragraphs, it's probably worth it to read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Answer (score 5):

You should absolutely definitely read [the answer linked in comments by MadHatter](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab). However it is also possible to highlight the specific reasons that the letter gives for rejection.

1. As the second bullet point says, you did not explain where the deposits to your account came from. Transfers from your own bank account would not be a problem, but unless you show that they were from your own account they would "raise doubt". You fix this next time by including the statements for the account you transferred the money from. In any case you should have included statements for all your accounts. Make sure that all large transfers are explained with evidence to show where they came from.
2. If you state that your sister will be paying for some of your visit, then you need to include a letter from her stating what she will pay.
3. Your sister also needs to demonstrate that she can afford to pay what she says she will. Her bank statements say she does not have that much money, so the officer will assume that she really isn't going to pay it.

Be aware that fixing these items does not guarantee that you will be accepted, and that a second application soon after a rejected one will receive extra scrutiny. Also note that if you make a new application in the future and your sister (or yourself) has recently acquired a lot more money without a good explanation that will be considered suspicious.